# Rails - only render a partial if a particular page is being shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial

I have an application using Ajax, which helps as the whole page doesn't have to be refreshed each time the user clicks a link.

In application.html.erb file I have:

```
<body>
  <%= render :partial => 'layouts/user_page_with_map' if @show_map %> 

  <div class ='page-content'>     
     <%= content_for?(:body) ? yield(:body) : yield %>
  </div>

</body>
```

The Show method in my controller is:

```
  def show  
    @show_map = true  
    @review = Review.new
    @reviews = @user.reviews
  end
```

The problem is that the partial stays on my page all the time - the yield stuff appears underneath it. So if a person clicks 'Contact Us' or 'About Us', or whatever, it appears underneath the map stuff, even though it's not relevant to 'Contact Us' or 'About Us'.

I'm far from an expert in Ajax - got a lot of help, but it's very useful in removing the need -hopefully! - for all those page reloads. 
Is there a way to code it so the partial will only be visible if the link being clicked activates  the 'Show' page? Any other relevant advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Chris.

Comment: it is because your @show_map is true, and the value will always true?

Comment: Yes, with every Ajax call/click on my links it seems to bypass application.html.erb, where show_map is set.do you know if there's any way to check that page each time? I could do something like set show_map to false in the other controllers, but not much point of they're being bypassed.thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can сut you page content after you received it, in the ajax method. I would assume that you are using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  #...
  success: function(data) {
    $(".page-content").replaceWith($(data).find(".page-content"));
  }
});
```

My opinion, its the best way for you. In this case your backend don't care "should you render with layout or not".

Comment: Thanks, I'll look more into this later on.the reason I have to do this partial thing in the first place is because my google map isn't showing in my div, when called from Ajax.everything else shows, but the map is a big white box.any idea why this might be?

Comment: This happend, because google map cannot initialize correctly. Your should trigger resize event `google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize')` after you show popup div.

Comment: Hi, it's not a popup div - I presume you're talking about a pop up window?, but you've probably put me on the right track, and I'm looking into it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your controller is called `FooController`, and the action you are calling via Ajax is `bar`. The following is a suitable solution.

**config/routes.rb:**

```
get 'bar', to: 'foos#bar'
```

**app/controllers/foos_controller.rb:**

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
    layout false, only: [:bar]                    # <-- layout false is key

    def bar
        @results = Foo.get_results(bar_params)
    end

private

        def bar_params
            params.permit(:utf8, :query, :attribute1, :attribute2)
        end
end
```

**app/views/foos/bar.html.erb:**

```
<% @results.each do |result| %>
    <p><%= result.inspect %></p>
<% end %>
```